# SQL Server stored procedure - Is it possible to return multiple results within a field of each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am wondering if it's possible to return multiple results within a column of each row or the best way to get multiple results within a column.

Example if you have a stored procedure that will return multiple students, but one of the columns within the student table is the photo id. A student can have several photos, but this stored procedure needs to return all three photo ids for each student.

```
SELECT 
    S.Name AS Name,
    (SELECT S.Id FROM COURSES WHERE P.StudentId = S.Id) AS PhotoId
FROM 
    PHOTOS P
INNER JOIN 
    PHOTOS P ON P.StudentId = S.Id
```

The example above will not work, but I need to know what is the best way of doing it. As the maximum number of pictures is set to 3, I was thinking to create each photo id within a separate column such as the following.

```
SELECT 
    S.Name AS Name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 S.Id FROM COURSES WHERE P.StudentId = S.Id) AS PhotoId1,
    (SELECT TOP 2 S.Id FROM COURSES WHERE P.StudentId = S.Id) AS PhotoId2,
    (SELECT TOP 3 S.Id FROM COURSES WHERE P.StudentId = S.Id) AS PhotoId3
FROM 
    PHOTOS P
INNER JOIN 
    PHOTOS P ON P.StudentId = S.Id
```

In this case only the top line would work. Instead of using `TOP 2` and `TOP 3` what is the equivalent of taking taking only the second and third result (same as in `Linq` `Take(1)` and `Skip(1)`).

Or is there a better way of doing it? Also I must make sure each student is only returned once even if they have multiple images

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain which way you are hoping to structure your data with photos in a row or photos in separate columns. However, Rows seem more natural to me.

**Rows**

```
SELECT  ph.Name 
      , PhotoId = co.Id

FROM    dbo.Photos      (NOLOCK)     ph
JOIN    dbo.Courses     (NOLOCK)     co ON co.Id = ph.StudentId
```

Output:

Name    | PhotId

Edward  | 1234

Edward  | 2345

Edward  | 3456

*Updated*

**Columns**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
            SELECT  ph.Name 
                  , PhotoId =   co.Id
                  , RN      =   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ph.Name ORDER BY co.Id)

            FROM    dbo.Photos      (NOLOCK)     ph
            JOIN    dbo.Courses     (NOLOCK)     co ON co.Id = ph.StudentId
        )

SELECT  Name 
      , PhotoId1 = SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Id ELSE NULL END)  
      , PhotoId2 = SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Id ELSE NULL END)  
      , PhotoId3 = SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Id ELSE NULL END)  

FROM CTE

GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: The first example does exactly the same as yours. Unfortunately I need it the other way. A student should only be displayed in one row with all his/her photo ids

Comment: In that case, I would recommend creating a CTE using a ROW_NUMBER function to help pivot out your PhotoIds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using row_number to get 1, 2 and 3 photos

```
SELECT S.Name AS Name
,(select x.photo_id from (SELECT PHOTO_ID, row_number() over (order by photo_id) row_num  from PHOTOS P where p.student_id = s.studenT_id) x where x.row_num = 1) AS PhotoId1
,(select x.photo_id from (SELECT PHOTO_ID, row_number() over (order by photo_id) row_num  from PHOTOS P where p.student_id = s.studenT_id) x where x.row_num = 2) AS PhotoId2
,(select x.photo_id from (SELECT PHOTO_ID, row_number() over (order by photo_id) row_num  from PHOTOS P  where p.student_id = s.studenT_id) x where x.row_num = 3) AS PhotoId3
FROM STUDENTS S
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but it does not work. The error message I get is `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` Also I need to mention this stored procedure already using `row_number()`, but I guess it should not matter. If the statement is correct, it should only return one result each, I have checked the database

Comment: no longer need the partition so just order by.. see updated script

Comment: I used the order by both ways, still did not get the right results. It does get all images, however create a new row for each result